# Ember js filtering the the data from the model

Tags: ember.js, filter

I am trying to filter the data from the ember model but I am unable to find the solution.

#### The file is in app/routes/notes.js

```
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';

export default Route.extend({
  model()  {
    let l = this.store.findAll('note');
    return l;
  }
});
```

#### The file is app/templates/note.hbs

```
 {{#each model  as |note|}}
   Title: {{note.title}}<br/>
   Description: {{note.description}}<br/>
   Date:{{note.date}}<br/>
 {{/each}}
```

I am trying to filter the data return from a model but it is not working as I am thought.The JSON format used in this is

```
{title: title, description: description, date:date, status: status}
```

I want to filter the output based upon the status and display on the template. But I'm unable to modify the data it showing some errors. I Have tried filtered from the model itself or by controllers actions but not worked. Can anyone suggest the solution?

Comment: Question 1: Is your payload returning the information you need?

Comment: Question 2: Are you able to watch payload returned into the ember data? (You can check it using the Ember Inspector addon)

Comment: Question 3: Can you provide a more complete example of your code via a repo, gist or a ember-twiddle? (https://ember-twiddle.com/)

Comment: How have you tried to filter the data?

Comment: yes it is returning a payload yes I am able to watch the payload.I need to filter the model based up on the status value.

Comment: I dont want to use any addon to filter the data.I want to write my own filter using helpers can anyone suggest me with this.I am new to ember I cannot  found any clear tutorial for writing this filters using helpers by #each.

Comment: project repo: https://github.com/SyamPhanindraChavva/trell-app-front-end @hernanvicente

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter just once:

```
model() {
  return this.store.findAll('note').then((data) => {
    return data.filter(({ status }) => status === 'HELLO');
  }); // see ES6 Promise specification for .then
}
```

Dynamic server-side filtering:

```
// route.js
queryParameters: {
  status: { refreshModel: true }
},
model({ status }) {
  return this.store.query('note', { status: status });
}

// controller.js
queryParameters: ['status']

status: 'HELLO'

// e.g. user could change 'status' using dropdown
```

Dynamic client-side filtering:

```
// route.js
model() {
  return this.store.findAll('note');
}

// controller.js
selectedStatus: 'SOME',
filteredModel: computed('model.length', 'selectedStatus', function() {
  return this.get('model').filterBy('status', this.get('selectedStatus'));
})
```